# I've been trying to wrap my head around the use of eigenvalues in cluster analysis. What does it tell me about my clustering behavior?

Tags: clustering, sas, eigenvalues

In a typical hierarchical cluster output from using SAS, the first table given lists all of the eigenvalues.

From what I understand, eigenvalues are derived from covariance between the variables. What I fail to understand is how this would assist me in understanding the underlying clustering behavior.

Anyone know a simple answer of why the eigenvalues are important to know for cluster analysis?

Here's the output:
[image]

Comment: Can you explain what hierarchical cluster analysis approach you are doing in SAS? Can you post some of the output from the analysis? Your question needs clarification in this regard otherwise it is not clear what is being asked.

Comment: `proc cluster data=random_data method=ward; var variable_list; run;`

Comment: It's interesting, because, for example, SPSS outputs no eigenvalues. I think you should find and read the SAS algorithms documentation. By the way, is Ward's "Mimimum Variance" method the same thing as commonly used Ward's minimum sum-of-squares method?

Comment: @ttnphns: I think so: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ward%27s_method#The_minimum_variance_criterion

Comment: I find this puzzling, particularly for *hierarchical* cluster analysis, because HCA produces a dendrogram rather than a division into clusters. Clusters are obtained by cutting the dendrogram, but that needs another decision and of course then  between-cluster and either per-cluster or pooled within-cluster covariance matrices could be calculated (should still be specified). The only covariance matrix that makes sense without specification of how to cut the dendrogram would be the covariance of the whole data set - but that would be PCA, not part of an HCA. Does the manual say anything?

Comment: @cbeleites, I was asking because there exist a version of Ward method, called Ward-Burr variance method of clustering. It's rarely used.

Comment: @ttnphns: aha. Never heard of that one till now. Could you post a link to an explanation? (though I'm afraid this gets off-topic for the question)

Comment: @cbeleites, Not now. I have to dig, and to study the differences myself, 'cause I'm interested myself.

Comment: I'm not feeling that bad anymore, this little eigen table is a mystery! It makes sense to me only in a PCA, not in hierarchical clustering. I'll still wait and hope someone knows. I've read the SAS documentation but its obscured in academic shop talk.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I teach cluster analysis and it baffles me as well.  If you give PROC CLUSTER a distance matrix it does not produce this.  It is not needed and I usually therefore add the "noeigen" option otherwise, so that it is omitted.   The only reason I can think for including it is to help you understand something of the structure of the data you are giving it and how correlated the variables are. i.e. to give you a sneak look at principal components.  It does not help you pick the number of clusters.

Before clustering you should consider if the data needs preparing in any way.  For example, outliers or highly skewed data can lead to one or two clusters with most of the observations and some other clusters with just one or two observations.  So taking a transformation of the data or removing outliers can help.   It is nearly always worth standardising the data otherwise the variables which are large values and with the most variability will dominate the clusters.

If there is a mix of variables some of which are unique and some of which are correlated with each other (e.g. age and years of employment) one way of pre-processing this is to carry out principal components. Otherwise it is as if you were using some facets of the data more than once (age approx equal year of employment +17; so having both of the these in means age is added twice).  If you use principal components first, then cluster on the first so many components this issue is avoided. That is the only reason why I can think of that SAS includes it here. So by looking at this first you can decide if you should have done this.

SAS does calculate something called the cubic clustering criteria (CCC) see this:
http://support.sas.com/documentation/onlinedoc/v82/techreport_a108.pdf

and buried in the middle of this is something about applying PCA to construct this statistic. It relates to constructing "hyper-cubes" and PCA can make this work faster.  It is mentioned in their documentation as well with reference to the CCC.   However I have yet to find any references to this criteria outside of SAS.

Personally, regarding the eigen analysis,  I leave it out.  If you do want to do PCA first then do it properly and use PRIC PRINCOMP first!  Otherwise just add the noeigen option.  That is what I get my students to do.

Comment: +1. I appreciate the thoughtful analysis of the situation and helpful advice.  Welcome to our site!

Answer (score -1):

1 shows that that factor is not dependent on other while, 0 eigen value shows it depends or has collinearlity with others.
Convert cumulative to percentage in the end its alwaz 100%

this table is used while choosing number of factor in factor analysis

Here we have a trade off b/w low eigen and high cumulative(that shows the variance amongst these factor)
we want to cover high variance and have clusters of factors that are separeted hence eigen value 1.
If you get 2 or 3 or 6 its the vector length of it :-P